# SSH tunnel issues since setting up public key login

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I'm trying to create an SSH tunnel using the command:

```
ssh -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 remoteserver
```

Previously, I had not set up public/private key login (for passwordless login). Using this command would then prompt me for a password, then just sit there and hang while the tunnel was open. Now that I've set setup the passwordless login, this command actually LOGS me into the remoteserver and brings up a shell, when I simply just want it to open the tunnel. Help please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `man ssh`:

```
-N   Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports (protocol version 2 only).
```

So, use `ssh -N -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 remoteserver`

Not having a shell with password-based login is not normal, are you sure you didn't change something else as well?

Comment: `ssh -fNn` is usually nice to run :)

Comment: -N is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.